# How to define an auxiliary function within a function

Tags: functions, scoping

I would like to define a function within a function to serve as an auxiliary function. In essence, something like this:

```
f[x_,y_]:=Module[{g[z_]:=2z},x+g[y]]
```

Where both f and g are in reality complicated functions. But this does not work because Module, or With, do not accept rule delayed in their definitions.

```
f[1,2]
Module::lvset: Local variable specification {g[z_]:=2 z} contains g[z_]:=2 z, which is an assignment to g[z_]; only assignments to symbols are allowed.
```

Is there a way around it?

Comment: Check the second example in documentation for `Module`...

Comment: Indeed, I missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want, you can use

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{g}, g[z_] := 2 z; x + g[y]]
```

Comment: How to increase reputation fast: answer the easy questions before they get marked as duplicates :p